# Wrong line comment in an HTML file in style tag (using Ctrl+/ ) in VS Code

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, comments

I've noticed that when I try to add a line comment in an HTML file in style tag (using Ctrl+/ ), instead of this: `/**/`, I get this `<!-- -->` in VS Code

The image of the issue:
[image: The image of the issue]

I try to comment in CSS format(`/**/`) but I got html `<!---->` comment format. Pls anyone who know this how to solve this. And PLS tell me that it is happening because of what and how?. I've tried to search it but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely happening because you're writing CSS in an HTML file, and VSC is likely not programmed for these edge cases. Use a different file for your CSS. I tried searching for an extension that might solve the issue but I couldn't find anything - perhaps you or someone else can find it?

Answer (score 0):

It actually works fine on my VSCode I'm using the latest version (1.79) user install.

You can try setting a keyboard shortcut for toggle comment here:
`Settings > keyboard shortcuts > Emmet Toggle Comment`

Add a keybinding it, and it must work then.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it.

It is happening because of some extension you have installed i had installed "Jinja By wholroyd" and because of that it was happening.

And if you have not installed the jinja extension which i mentioned earlier and it's still happening then
go to extension section and see extension you have installed and try to disable the extension one by one.

And then go to code file and try to comment using short cut key and see that the comment is working or not after you disabled the extension.

If it works after disabling the specific extension it means it was the one who was causing this.